# How to limit du output to a specific user?

Tags: linux, disk-space-utilization, gnu, du

I need to help a specific user, say alice, free up some disk space; but not all the user's files are in his home directory; many are in directories shared with other users. I'd like to have something like the output of

```
du -sh *
```

but limited to the files that belong to that user only. I.e., something like,

```
du -sh --ignore-all-users-except=alice *
```

So, for example, if in the current directory there are three directories, `a`, `b` and `c`, I'd like to see output such as the following:

```
1.3G   a
416K   b
80K    c
```

meaning that alice is using 1.3G inside `a`, 416K inside `b`, and so on.

Is there any utility that can give me such information, or do I need a script?

Answer (score 4):

```
find / -user alice -print0 | du -ch --files0-from=-
```

Comment: Thanks. This is indeed good as a starting point. It misses ``-type f`` (otherwise it counts some files twice or more times if they are inside a directory owned by alice), and I also use ``tail -n 1``. Actually the full command that does what I want is ``for x in *; do find $x -type f -user alice -print0 | du -ch --files0-from=-|tail -n 1|awk '{ printf "%-10s", $1 }'; echo $x; done``

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do.

```
find . -user alice -type f -exec du -h {} +
```

Update:
You might want to check the answers [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/94663/disk-usage-per-user-in-linux-unix)

Comment: Neither the find command nor the linked post does what I want, as the first gives a huge list of files and the second concerns usage across the entire file system, whereas I want a sum per specific directories.